# Deployed a react project. It's only showing a blank page instead of the project

Tags: reactjs, github-pages

I see other topics regarding this issue, but following their advice has not helped my particular issue.

I have tried following the https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/ documentation on the github pages section. It didn't work the first time, so I thought maybe I did something wrong. So, I also did a hard reset, and started back over and tried it again.

Yesterday I published my calculator project to git hub pages. I then deleted it because someone told me I wouldn't be able to post a dynamic site on there. Well I later found out that a simple calculator is not dynamic site because its not accessing a server. So, I decided to try and post it to gh pages once again. Once again, the gh page is showing a blank page. Apparently this is a common issue.

the gh page link: https://benjamin-wofford.github.io/Purple-Calculator/

and the repository link: https://github.com/Benjamin-Wofford/Purple-Calculator/tree/gh-pages

Please help guide me so that I can get my calculator up on the internet

Comment: You might be missing a homepage path in your package.json. If thats's the case then you'll only have to add `"homepage": "."`

Comment: I've implemented that. It's step one of the deployment article. No change so far.

Comment: Maybe specifying the homepage url helps, here's a thread with the same issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54427793/getting-blank-page-after-react-app-publish-in-github

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My manifest.json file somehow was built using HTML code. So, I switched out the code with the actual manifest.json file that was on my local repository, and it fixed the issue.