# React app deployment on github pages shows a blank page

Tags: reactjs, github, npm, github-pages

I'm just starting with react and I built my first application and now I'm trying to deploy it on github pages but the page is completely blank. The steps I followed are:

1. Install gh-pages: `npm install gh-pages --save`
2. Add homepage to package.json:  `"homepage": "https://milind452.github.io/my-reads/"`
3. Add scripts: `"predeploy": "npm run build",  "deploy": "gh-pages -d build"`
4. Deploy: `npm run deploy`

I can see that the gh-pages branch is created and a deployment is also created; but the page is blank and nothing shows on the console. I checked the sources in the dev-tools and all the files are there.

I also checked my repo pages settings and the source for deployment is set to gh-pages branch. I'm not sure what is happening.

I also checked out this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54427793/getting-blank-page-after-react-app-publish-in-github) but none of the answers there seemed to solve it for me.

Here is the [github repo](https://github.com/milind452/my-reads) and the deployment [link](https://milind452.github.io/my-reads/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Never use `BrowserRouter` on GitHub Pages. There are some issues with it, it always shows blank screen. Use `HashRouter` instead, that will most probably work.

```
import { HashRouter } from "react-router-dom";

// some code here

return (
    <HashRouter base="/">
        <App />
    </HashRouter>
)
```

Comment: Thanks @tomasxboda Using HashRouter worked but it shows a '#' symbol in the url. Is there any way around this?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think there is. However, if you are planning to deploy your app in the future, you can use the original `BrowserRouter` almost everywhere. The only place where it does not work is GitHub Pages, so you'll have to stick to `HashRouter` for now.

Comment: Glad I could help!

Comment: I've tried using HashRouter instead of BrowserRouter, but I'm still getting a blank page with error "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404" Any idea how to fix this please ?

Answer (score 1):

The create react app documentation says that:

> GitHub Pages doesn’t support routers that use the HTML5 `pushState`
> history API under the hood (for example, React Router using
> `browserHistory`). This is because when there is a fresh page load for a
> url like http://user.github.io/todomvc/todos/42, where `/todos/42` is a
> frontend route, the GitHub Pages server returns 404 because it knows
> nothing of `/todos/42`. If you want to add a router to a project hosted
> on GitHub Pages, here are a couple of solutions:
>
> - You could switch from using HTML5 history API to routing with hashes. If you use React Router, you can switch to `hashHistory` for this effect, but the URL will be longer and more verbose (for example, http://user.github.io/todomvc/#/todos/42?_k=yknaj). [Read more](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Router) about different history implementations in React Router.

Therefore you should use `hashHistory` if you want to host your site on GitHub Pages.
Here is the [link](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#notes-on-client-side-routing) to documentation.

If you don't wish to change router, try deploying it on [Netlify](https://www.netlify.com/with/react/) which is also another free hosting provider. But again for Netlify deployment, follow the [documentation](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#netlify), which says:

To support `pushState`, make sure to create a `public/_redirects` file with the following rewrite rules:

```
/*  /index.html  200
```

Comment: I added the `public/_redirects` file with the given rule but the netlify deployment did not work. It shows a blank page. Here's the netlify deployment [link](https://blissful-brattain-ab548b.netlify.app/). For the deployment settings I did not change anything and left the default settings.